# Google Maps not working HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I registered the key for google maps in my website. Everything was working until recently it stopped showing with an error, but for some reason its works fine on mobile view.

Here's an image of what's happening[image]

Here's the code

```
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var LatLng = {lat: 25.09112766, lng: 55.1534003};
          var mapProp = {

            center:new google.maps.LatLng(25.09112766,55.1534003),
            zoom:16,
                scrollwheel: false,
                navigationControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                draggable: false,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLng,
                map: map,
              });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

These errors are usually generated from an ad blocking plugin, such as Adblock Plus. To test this use either a different browser or uninstall the ad blocking plugin (right clicking the extension by the URL bar and clicking "Remove from Chrome...").

There is an easier way to temporarily disable an extension. In Chrome, opening an Incognito tab will usually stop extensions running (unless you have specifically told Chrome which ones to run in Incognito).

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm in Incognito!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's common for these error to appear if you have **Ad Blocker** turned on. Try turning it off and see if it persists.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!